# Botões com aparência diferente em tempo de design e de execução

Tags: delphi, button

Alguém já teve o problema acima ? Em tempo de desenvolvimento o desenho do botão é normal. Porém, após compilar e rodar a aplicação, os mesmos se parecem com botões da época do Windows98.

[image: Imagem de design time]

[image: Imagem em runtime]

Windows 7 - 64 bits
Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Obrigado por qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Pressione Ctrl + Shift + F11, para abrir as opções do projeto.
Provavelmente isso está acontecendo, porque você esta com esta opção desmarcada:

[image]

Comment: Valeu pela força, Victor. É isso mesmo. Isso tem relação com o arquivo Manifest.xml, correto ?

Comment: Sim. Antigamente a unica coisa que costumávamos mexer no arquivo `manifest`, era questão de permissões, mas hoje tem essa opção `Enable Adm Privileges`, então acredito que dificilmente vamos mexer nele manualmente.